# How to access PyNode from a PyNode list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya, pymel

I ran this example code with 2 polyCubes in scene.

```
import pymel.core as pymel

pymel.select('pCube1', 'blinn1')
print pymel.ls(sl = True)
print pymel.ls(sl = True)[0]
```

and this is my output

```
[nt.Transform(u'pCube1'), nt.Blinn(u'blinn1')]
pCube1
```

I know the elements inside this list are PyNodes, but printing them gives out a string type name of the node. Is there anyway to access the PyNode directly from this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

So apparently the Script Editor returns a representation of PyNode when we print it. Like it's an overloaded **str**. It is still a PyNode but looks like a string only in Maya's Script Editor. To make it actually appear like a PyNode, we have to use repr() or enclose in back-ticks (`)

Here is the link where I found the answer.
: http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/pymel/tutorial.html

Formatting: Read Me First to Avoid Confusion section